# Unknown "System.Object" to "string" or XML

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework with

```
  var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>(dynamicSQLString);
  var res = result.ToList();
```

Where dynamicSQLString can be anything... can return a "count()", can be a select with a list of rows.... etc.... there is no way to match it with a known class type. So I thought of using "object".

I would like to know if this is the way to go, and if it is, how can I "convert" the result into a "string"...... ?

Is this even possible?

**Update #1**

```
var t1 = result.GetType(); //System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlQuery
var res = result.ToList();
var first = res.First();                
var t2 = first.GetType(); // System.Object
```

If I do a count on "res" I get the expected number of rows, but I do NOT see a way to get the "property names" of this object/dynamic row, neither it's values.

**Update #2**

I've found a "similar" example, but in there the person knows exactly the parameters/types the select will return.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-4-1-SqlQuery

Comment: If you are doing this, why use entity framework? If you have a class with public setters that match the column names of the result set, and a default constructor (i.e. a POCO) then you should pass that as the type parameter.

Comment: @jodrell legacy reasons and I can not use ado.net or something else....

Comment: so you don't want to know if this is "the way to go" as its already the only way.

Comment: it obviously depends on what you want to do with the data after the query. You could do a simple `GetType()` on the result before adding to the list.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't convert the result into string unless your SQL query
(in this case dynamicSQLString) 
return premitive primitive  such as
"select name from customers" that return a string result for each row in database

Comment: That seems to be the problem... each row may be a "list" of "things" of different types..... This is why I was thinking even if it is possible to cast everything into a IDictionary and then somehow do a "ToString()" on each value.... but I am not even able to make the first "cast".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the dynamic type instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

However you will need to do some casting on it before you can put it into a list.